# Scroll Length Upon Down Arrow Press

Tags: html, browser

What is the length of scroll upon pressing the down arrow. I imagine it is standardized. It's probably in pixels. But I can't seem to find a protocol anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think its 35 pixels for chrome on windows 8.1 (normal desktop mode). It might depend on browsers or OS though.